# Creating Worker in Web browser

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a issue with looping all the elements data which is present in the viewer which I have to achieve without running in the main viewer browser, but instead want to run the memory intensive task in the worker.js file.
How to create a worker file which can take the memory load without affecting the viewer & the loading of all elements

Can you give a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a worker using the [executeUserFunction](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Private/PropDbLoader/#executeuserfunction-code-userdata)

Here is a sample showing how to use it:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/executeuserfunction-accepts-user-data